# Traitor tracing - codeword properties

Tags: coding-theory, traitor-tracing

Let $c ≥ 2$. A code $C ⊂ Q^n$
is a $c$-frameproof code if for any set
$X ⊂ C$ with $|X| ≤ c$ we have
desc$(X) ∩ C = X$.
Thus the only codewords that a coalition of up to $c$ pirates is capable of producing are those
that already belong to members of that coalition. To see a definition of desc$(X)$, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/46648/traitor-tracing-determining-a-set-of-codewords?noredirect=1#comment104489_46648).

What I want to know is, from the definition above can I say the following is **not** a 2-frameproof code?

$012,011,222,112$

As for example $012$ and $011$ agree in more than one position but I don't know if it must be the case that for any two of the codewords, they will have to agree in more than one position?? As $222$ and $112$ only agree in one position for example.

Comment: Can you show you understand the answer to the linked question by listing the vectors in $desc(C)$ in your example above. You can edit this question.

Answer (score 1):

**General method:**

Let $X=\{222,112\}$ be a group of two traitors we focus on. Clearly (see my answer to your earlier question)
$$\mathrm{desc}(X)=\{1,2\}\times \{1,2\}\times \{2\}=\{222,122,212,112\}
$$
is the set of vectors these two users can create if they collude.
Since $\mathrm{desc}(X)\cap C=X$, this is not a contradiction to the code being $2-$frameproof.

**Edit:** *Intuitively, two users can compare their symbols at each position and choose to use either symbol, if their symbols are distinct. If by doing this they can generate a third user's codeword, they can frame him/her by using his/her codeword. The code symbol alphabet will be very large and you can think of code symbols as cryptographic keys, and the whole codeword as a concatenated key. Thus it is infeasible to brute force the keys except by learning them with pairwise sharing between coalitions of users (called traitors).*

You need to do this for all sets $X$ made up of 2 codewords and verify the e  equality holds. The overlap of codewords does not allow you a shortcut to decide if the code is $2-$frameproof.

**For a small code:**

Can we find two codewords that allow two traitors to build a third codeword thus frame a third user?

YES. Using $X=\{011,112\}$ we can build $012$ which is another codeword. So this code is not $2-$frameproof. Thus if Alice is the user who is assigned codeword $011$ and Bob is the user who is assigned the codeword $112$ they can generate the vectors in $desc(X)$ and in fact they can pretend to be Harry, the user who is assigned the codeword $012$, and frame him by, e.g. downloading a movie which will be charged to his account.

Comment: @harry55 do you understand the answer?